# What is the next set of boxes in this sequence?

Tags: pattern, visual

[image]

I don't know the answer, but I'm sure someone here can figure it out.
Have fun!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The answer is

> (b)

Arguments:

> Ignore the squares, and just look at the diagonal lines inside the squares.
>  The first four boxes spell out S,H,E,L.
>  Box (b) contains an "L" and completes the word to SHELL.

Answer (score 7):

I think the answer is

> (b)

because

> If you look at the shapes formed by the diagonal lines in each of the diagrams, they form capital letters - S, H, E, L. (b) also contains L while (d) seems to contain C but it makes more sense that it would be spelling the word SHELL rather than SHELC